# How to send any structure as parameter to a method and return the structure?

Tags: go, struct, yaml

I'm new to Go and I'm seeing if there's a way to have a method that receives any structure as parameter.

I have something like this in my code that is a function that does exactly the same for 5 structures and returns the same structure,  but I don't know if I can do that. I'm wondering if I can do something like this:

```
type Car struct {
     Model   string `yaml:"Model"`
     Color   string `yaml:"Color"`
     Wheels  int    `yaml:Wheels"`
     Windows int    `yaml:"Windows"` 
}

type Motorcycle struct {
     Model    string `yaml:"Model"`
     Color    string `yaml:"Color"`
     Wheels   int      `yaml:Wheels"`
}

type Bus struct {
     Model      string `yaml:"Model"`
     Color      string `yaml:"Color"`
     Wheels     int    `yaml:Wheels"`
     Passengers int    `yaml:"Passengers"`
}

func main () {

    car := GetYamlData(Car)
    motorcycle := GetYamlData(Motorcycle)
    Bus := GetYamlData(Bus)
}

func GetYamlData(struct anyStructure) (ReturnAnyStruct struct){

       yaml.Unmarshal(yamlFile, &anyStructure)

       return anyStructure
}
```

Is possible to do something like the code above? Actually what I have is something like this:

```
func main(){
   car, _, _ := GetYamlData("car")
    _,motorcycle,_ := GetYamlData("motorcycle")
    _,_,bus := GetYamlData("bus")
 }

func GetYamlData(structureType string) (car *Car, motorcycle *Motorcycle, bus *Bus){

 switch structureType{

        case "car":
                yaml.Unmarshal(Filepath, car)
        case "motorcycle":
                yaml.Unmarshal(Filepath, motorcycle)
        case "bus":
                yaml.Unmarshal(Filepath, bus)
 }

 return car, motorcycle, bus

}
```

With the time this will be increasing and it will return a lot of values and I don't want a lot of return values, is there a way to do it with the first code that I posted?

Comment: What is the purpose to having types with identical structures that are all handled exactly the same way?

Comment: Well, that was just an example, I didn't want to post my real code but those structures are differentes values and they are variable, those are not the same, i'll edit my post to avoid any confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it the exact same way `yaml.Unmarshal` does it, by taking in a value to unmarshal into:

```
func GetYamlData(i interface{}) {
    yaml.Unmarshal(Filepath, i)    
}
```

Example usage:

```
func main () {
    var car Car
    var motorcycle Motorcycle
    var bus Bus
    GetYamlData(&car)
    GetYamlData(&motorcycle)
    GetYamlData(&bus)
}
```

Comment: How could return the structure with their values filled and assign it to a structure, I mean something like this: `car := GetYamlData(Car)` 
Return the .yaml filled with their values and assign it to a new structure object

Comment: You get the exact same behavior with the suggested solution above. Is there some particular reason to insist it be a return value instead of a reference parameter? Because that will drastically increase the complexity of the solution.

Comment: Thanks Adrian, the code above is working but the values of the structure are not filled but looking in the interface, it is retrieving the data, i just need figure out how to assign those to the corresponding value of the structure.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - you said it's filling in the values but it's not filling in the values? Which is it?

Comment: What I mean is fill the "struct" properties with the function "GetYamlData", the interface contain the data from the .yaml file but I have to figure out how to assign the .yaml values to the structure properties.

Comment: Pass the struct to the function, just like you would with `yaml.Unmarshal`, since it's just a wrapper of `yaml.Unmarshal`. Without seeing the code you're actually using, it's hard to offer any more advice.

Comment: Added example usage to the answer, hope it helps.

Comment: That was terrific! that's what exactly what I wanted to do! Thanks Adrian.

Comment: @JavierSalas Might I add my two cents. One of the beauties of Go, is that Go is written in Go. In cases like this, you can inspect the standard libraries' code to "see how it's done". Obviously, knowing where to look and what to look for is the more difficult part, but it's a great way to see what goes on "under the hood" and adapt your own code and coding behaviors.